# Android Eclipse ADT Widget Palette

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm learning how to build android apps and I have a simple question about the Eclipse ADT software. I tried to figure out the reason on google but I was unlucky.
Does anyone could explain me why I have an old widget palette on my Eclipse ADT? The guy at Lynda works with different widgets and the Google Developer site shows a different palette too.
Thanks in advance!

My Palette / Tutorial Palette / Google Site 
[Palette's Differences pic](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bljun7QCAAEG9Hc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The palette shows how the widgets will look in the theme selected, for the selected device / API level. Change the theme (and the API version) to see how the widgets look in the particular theme / OS version.

[image: Device / Theme / API selection toolbar]